# How to define length of properties

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to know what is best practice when defining length of properties?

Can I just use any length?

What about drop-down, radio button and check box, do I need to define the length as well?

What about date created, user create type properties?

or decimal or integer properties.

I am planning on using Fluent API in the onModelCreating function instead of using the data annotations.

Comment: That's a very broad question that can be hard to answer without more details. Generally you don't want to use more space than you need, but still have enough cushion to be flexible and handle changes in the future. Boolean checkboxes, for example, generally use a bit field in the database instead of a char/varchar,  dropdowns usually store an ID value not the text, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't just use any length.  Each primitive type within .Net has a limitation on its size. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360(v=vs.90).aspx) as a reference.

Also keep in mind that the type of datastore you use (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle DB etc) has its own limitations in terms of their underlying data types which are mapped by EF to .Net primitive types.  You should be OK as long as you stick with DB's that has out-of-the-box EF integration.  For roll-your-own integrations you might want to limit field sizes to the least size between CSharp primitives and DB data types.

As a rule-of-thumb, you should specify maximum field sizes only when dictated by business rules or requirements, or when a performance issue of some kind arises.

Comment: By any length I meant like for example .HasMaxLength(9), .HasMaxLength(75) or .HasMaxLength(76) I realize there is probably a min and max length. If I look at the SQL table there is already predefine length nvarchar(50) and such.

Comment: Sure, I understand.  As I stated in my answer, you should define this only if your business requirements dictate as such, or if you are experiencing performance or scalability issues.

Comment: I wish someone could post a sample of a model class with all the properties and a sample of an EntityTypeConfiguration class. It still not clear to me the whole concept. I will have fields like State, city, First name, Last Name, job title, etc. What about radio buttons, do I need to specify the length. Do I even need to specify the length.

Comment: Cindy, from what I can gather around your current level of knowledge on the subject I would strongly advise that you start off by using data annotations as they are much easier to use.  This will allow you to understand the base concepts first before progressing to using the somewhat more complex fluent API.  I also agree with @David Godwin that your question is very broad.  In general, your chances of getting a good answer on StackOverflow are better when you ask clear and precise questions.  I would also recommend you work through a some of the many ASP.Net MVC tutorials that are available.

Comment: Sir Juice, Whether I use data annotation or Fluent API it will still not give me the best practice on how to determine the length for string properties. I have already done the MVC tutorials plus read a book. When you learn something on your own without a team sometimes it is heard to know if you are in the right direction. I guess I was just hoping to see someone else simple sample to confirm.  I will mark your answer as right for spending time to help me. Thanks